# jupyter container can't identify pyspark container

Tags: docker, pyspark, docker-compose, jupyter

this is my docker-compose code. I want to have spark and jupyter containers and run spark commands on jupyter container. Fortunatley both containers start successfully after runing `docker-compose up` command. The problem is jupyter container can't identify spark container and retrives `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyspark'` error after runing `from pyspark.sql import SparkSession` command in jupyter UI. Thank you very much in advance

```
'version: '2'
services:
   spark:
      image: docker.io/bitnami/spark:3.4
      environment:
       - SPARK_MODE=master
       - SPARK_MASTER_URL=spark://spark-master:7077
       - SPARK_RPC_AUTHENTICATION_ENABLED=no
       - SPARK_RPC_ENCRYPTION_ENABLED=no
       - SPARK_LOCAL_STORAGE_ENCRYPTION_ENABLED=no
       - SPARK_SSL_ENABLED=no
       - SPARK_USER=spark
      ports:
        - '8080:8080'
      networks:
        - sparknet
    spark-worker:
      image: docker.io/bitnami/spark:3.4
      environment:
          - SPARK_MODE=worker
          - SPARK_MASTER_URL=spark://spark:7077
          - SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY=1G
          - SPARK_WORKER_CORES=1
          - SPARK_RPC_AUTHENTICATION_ENABLED=no
          - SPARK_RPC_ENCRYPTION_ENABLED=no
          - SPARK_LOCAL_STORAGE_ENCRYPTION_ENABLED=no
          - SPARK_SSL_ENABLED=no
          - SPARK_USER=spark
       networks:
          - sparknet
    jupyter:
      image: jupyter/datascience-notebook
      ports:
         - 8888:8888
      environment:
         - JUPYTER_ENABLE_LAB=yes
         - JUPYTER_TOKEN=my-secret-token
         - SPARK_MASTER_URL=spark://spark-master:7077
         - SPARK_MASTER_HOST=spark
      networks:
         - sparknet
      depends_on:
        - spark
networks:
     sparknet:'
```